# Instant Chat - Android using Sinch

Tags: android, sinch

I want to integrate Sinch for instant chat in my android app. I have not found any docs, tutorials or github samples for integrating Instant Chat. Please help me to find a way to integrate.

Comment: try here : https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/

Comment: you can try this https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#instantmessaging  else u can have a look at this github sample https://github.com/sinch/java-sms-tutorial

Comment: i don't think so, please check on doc.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar That link you provided works. Does sinch supports channels ?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar okay. Got it. Will any option exists to create like channel or room ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an android (JAVA) chat library I recommend [MQTT chat](https://mqtt-chat.com). It is more than a library, a complete messenger with extremely fast messages sending using the MQTT protocol and also it provides audio and video calls with webrtc. integration is also very easy. Even a beginner in Android can integrate it.

here is a tutorial on [how to integrate mqtt chat into an android application](https://mqtt-chat.com/developers/tutorials/2/How+to+easily+integrate+MQTT+Chat+android+library+version+1.2.0+in+any+android+application.).